# Failed Win8 App Certification: 3.10 - If your app includes an ARM or a Neutral package it must support Microsoft Direct3D feature level 9_1

Tags: windows-8, directx

My C# app uses a C++ WinRT component I've written to get a list of system fonts using Direct X.

This is based on this example:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd756582(v=VS.85).aspx

My app is published in the store, but my latest update failed to pass the store review process on point 3.10 complaining about my use of Direct 3D and how this might not run on ARM tablets. As far as I know I'm not using Direct 3D and the only Direct X feature I'm using is GetSystemFontCollection.

How can I make sure I don't fail this requirement and do I need to remove some rogue reference in my component to Direct3D?

Also, why am I failing this now, when it passed before?

Comment: looks like a failure of automated verification. Based on the code in your link you should be supporting 9_1 feature level just fine. Have you tried to run your app on Surface? Try to contact microsoft store ppl and explain your situation.

Comment: or if MS uses static code analysis you could try to fool them by creating dead code that creates d3d device with feature level of D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_9_1. And remember to test using dxcpl.exe, to emulate a 9_1 device.

Comment: Dennis, thanks for your comments. It turns out this wasn't really a failure reason and I'm really failing on something else. After pointing out in the tester notes how I use DirectX my next failure report was slightly more useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I submitted again and included a note to the tester explaining that my app didn't use any Direct 3D features, and I told them the exact DirectX function I did use.

I still failed, but the Direct3D reason was no longer one of the reasons.

Apparently my app is crashing, which was another failure reason the first time round, but I thought this must be related to the Direct3D problem. I can't reproduce the crash, but at least I now know that I can stop looking at my use of DirectX. This was a red herring.

Answer (score 1):

Did you target all three platforms or choose any cpu in your release?

Does this page help:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/apps/hh994923.aspx

It looks like you may have inadvertently requested a higher level.

Comment: When I build for store it produces 3 app packages and I send all three. So, I think I target all platforms. I've not fiddled with the build settings though, so I'm not sure how they work.
I've read the page about Direct X, but I don't know where I specify what version I'm using. I don't use any of the advanced features that would require a later version than 9_1.

Comment: Do you explicitly call D3D11CreateDevice?

from the page linked: "When testing your game, you can force a system with a higher feature level hardware to emulate a lower feature level using the dxcpl.exe tool included with Microsoft Visual Studio 2012. For example, using dxcpl.exe, you can force an 11_1 device to emulate a 9_1 device. If you are planning to support Windows RT devices or lower feature level platforms, make this tool an integral part of your test process."

Comment: Submitted again with note to tester and this is no longer noted as a problem. Looks like it was a red herring. Thanks for your help.